# fmt.Println is not executing in order when used without sleep

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I'm trying to understand, why my code doesn't behave as I expect it. The problem is that I would expect, that my code would behave like that:

1. Define channel
2. Run goroutine and start looping
3. Put value into channel, print "finished"
4. Starting second iteration, blocking call(there is already value in the channel), move to main goroutine
5. Printing 1, trying to run second iteration, blocking call for main goroutine, coming back to second goroutine
6. Cycle repeats

It works like that, but only with time.Sleep, but for some reason when commenting out time.Sleep it behaves totally different. What's even more interesting that sometimes for really small values of time like Nanos etc this code returns even more different results. Could someone explain me, why it works like that? My guess is that maybe Println is too slow on display, but it sounds weird to me..

Thanks

```
** As expected: **

finished
1
finished
2
finished
3
finished
6
finished
4
finished
8
finished all

** Not expected **

finished
1
2
finished
finished
3
finished
6
4
finished
finished
8
finished all
```

```
func main() {
    var c chan int = make(chan int)
    go sendingThrowingResults(c)

    for val := range c {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }

    fmt.Println("finished all")
}

func sendingThrowingResults(c chan int) {
    var results []int = []int{1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 8}

    for _, val := range results {
        //time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        c <- val
        fmt.Println("finished")
    }
    defer close(c)
}
```

Comment: The channel operation is the only synchronization point between the two goroutines.  It's possible for one goroutine to stop executing while the other goroutine continues executing until blocked by the next channel operation.

Comment: Yep, thats what I understand and described, but I would suspect that all the code in goroutine will be executed

Comment: What would be the way to fix it, I thought that channel's blocking behaviour should be enough

Comment: The code in each goroutine is fully executed in order.  Other than the synchronization point at the channel operation, there is no synchronization between the goroutines.

Comment: Here’s the sequence of events in the unexpected output:  S+R: send/recv; S: print finished; R: print 1; S+R: send/recv; R: print 2; S: print finished; …

Comment: Ok, sorry for late response. So can I say like that:
Go scheduler can stop goroutine from executing in basically every moment it wants, we don't have control over when scheduler stops execution of one goroutine and switches to another one, it can stop on blocking call or in a moment when it finds out that switching might be more effective option, although we have control over order of values send from channel and where we get it in program. In my example scheduler can switch whenever it wants in any point of program with preserving order of instructions in anonymous function, right?

Comment: To say more, fmt.Println is syscall underneath thats why it may recieve blocking call there, but it is not deal breaker since we know that still go scheduler can also switch to another goroutine in any random moment. Also this code may not execute on one core, but many, that might be also another reason it behaves like that: @CeriseLimón am I correct?

Comment: @Burak Serdar does it make sense?

Answer (score 3):

A channel operation needs both sides to participate. A write only happens when a reader is ready. Once that happens, there is no guarantee on which goroutine will run first.

Thus, once the channel write happens, one of the two printlns will work, in some random order.